# "Notice: Undefined index" when trying to read $_SESSION array

Tags: php, session

I have an irritating problem and I can't seem to fix it, I watched some videos on YouTube and read through the php.net documentation about error but this `$_SESSION` error needs your help!

The exact error, I get is this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: previouspage
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Localhost\root\test\index.php on line 5
```

What I have created is a goback button using a session variable. When the variable is already defined in my script there's no problem but when "the user" visits the website for the first time there is no "previous page" yet. The error above is what I then get. How can I fix this?

I have this PHP code:

```
<?php 

session_start();

if($_SESSION["previouspage"]) {
    echo "<a href=".$_SESSION["previouspage"].">Go back.</a>";
    $_SESSION["previouspage"] = "index.php";
}else {
    //No go back button will be displayed.
    $_SESSION["previouspage"] = "index.php";
}
```

?>

So, when there's no history yet I get the error, otherwise not. How to fix this?

Comment: No because when I click on undefined index it talks about arrays ;)

Comment: If you don't want to declare your session variables, you should turn off E_NOTICE level error reporting. You can do this in your php.ini. But I'd recommend you use `isset()` to check their existence instead of just `if($var)`.

Comment: `$_SESSION` is indeed an array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `isset()` function:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["previouspage"])) {
   echo "<a href=".$_SESSION["previouspage"].">Go back.</a>";
   $_SESSION["previouspage"] = "index.php";
}else {
    //No go back button will be displayed.
    $_SESSION["previouspage"] = "index.php";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the array `$_SESSION` doesn't have a key `previouspage`.

You can use the `empty` function to check that the key exists and that `$_SESSION["previouspage"]` has a value. Try using:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION["previouspage"])){
    //$_SESSION["previouspage"] exists!
}
```

Comment: thanks! I'll try. Finally someone that just explains it and not linking to other posts that don't make sense :)!

Comment: @danronmoon This is not the case. See http://uk3.php.net/empty `That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false`

Comment: @Jim you're right.  A notice is only raised for an undeclared variable

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
if( isset($_SESSION["previouspage"]) ){

    echo "<a href=".$_SESSION["previouspage"].">Go back.</a>";
    $_SESSION["previouspage"] = "index.php";
}else {
    //No go back button will be displayed.
    $_SESSION["previouspage"] = "index.php";
}
```